# json_object and dart:mirror

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am using json_object as in [Using Dart with JSON Web Services](https://webdev.dartlang.org/articles/get-data/json-web-service)

Code  works fine in Dartium. Upon building using dart_to_js_script_rewriter, warning is thrown.

> WARNING: dart:mirrors support in dart2js is experimental,
>   *          and not recommended.
>   *          This implementation of mirrors is incomplete,
>   *          and often greatly increases the size of the generated
>   *          JavaScript code.
>   *
>   * Your app imports dart:mirrors via: package:json_object => dart:mirrors

What are the good alternatives to  json_object ?   I know JSON.decode exists  but  I would like to avoid the Map API if possible

Comment: I am using only the first method as  shown in  [link] (https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject).  In other words I am not using ObjectToJSON method that uses mirrors.  I am still getting the above warning.

Answer (score 1):

To work with json, it is now recommended to use code generation if you work on a browser or reflection if you work on the Dart VM.

You can try package like [jaguar_serializer](https://github.com/Jaguar-dart/jaguar_serializer) that help you convert a JSON string into a Dart Object.